# How do you remove the Show Applications button?

Tags: 20.04

AskUbuntu! I am using Dash to Panel and love it ( I personally do not like or use Dash to Dock, but that's just me) in conjunction with ArcMenu on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. This combination makes the Show Applications button redundant and it's sticking out like a sore thumb. I tried toggling it off in dconf Editor (as shown in the pic below), but to no avail. Any other way to get rid or it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right Click on the *Show Applications* button.
2. Then click *Dash to Panel Settings*.
3. Click the highlighted *Visible* button adjacent to *Show Applications button*.

   [image]